# how clear text file with asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, text-files

I use this code to write into a text file in my code behinde:
            string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("s.txt");

```
    if (File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true);

        string logMessage = "ok";

        writer.WriteLine(logMessage);
        writer.Flush();
        writer.Close();
    }
```

how i can clear all data in this text file before writeing into this file?

Answer (score 0):

You are using the constructor that instructs the stream to Append to the existing file (or create a new one if it doesn't exist. Just change your constructor to

```
using(StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false))
{
  .....
}
```

and it will clear and rewrite your file

[MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36b035cb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about the second parameter

> appendType: System.Boolean
>
> true to append data to the file; false to overwrite the file. If the
>   specified file does not exist, this parameter has no effect, and the
>   constructor creates a new file.

Notice also that you should use the using statement around a Stream to be sure to properly close and dispose the underlying file system resource.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using false as your 2nd parameter instead of true.

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, false);
```

True indicates to append the text to the file.

Alternatively, you can also use the following code to remove all text from a file

```
File.WriteAllText(filePath, String.Empty);
```